# Best way to declare method parameter type list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I know the good way to put a parameter type list is:

```
def test(my_list = None):
    if my_list is None:
        my_list = []
```

But I don't understand why I cannot simply do something like:

```
def test(my_list = list)
```

I tried it in the console mode and works

Update

In '“Least Astonishment” and the Mutable Default Argument' they explain why we don't should use

```
def test(my_list = [])
```

not why I cannot use

```
def test(my_list = list)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Least Astonishment" and the Mutable Default Argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-and-the-mutable-default-argument)

Comment: Yeah it works... Till you find out that functions are first class objects and you start finding bugs. See the duplicate above.

Comment: Parameters *don't have types* `my_list=list` assigns the type (class) object `list` to the default.

Answer (score 0):

If you do `l=list`, you'll get this error:

```
def a(l=list):
    print([x for x in l])
a()

# >> TypeError: 'type' object is not iterable
```

What you want to do is `def a(l=list())`, which is exactly the same as `def a(l=[])`.

Then we fall back to the problem here: ["Least Astonishment" and the Mutable Default Argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-and-the-mutable-default-argument)

**Update**

If I understood you well, why not simply do:

```
def a(l=[]):
    l = l or []
    # ...rest of the method
```

Comment: I want, that the call of the method MUST be done with a list, and this is true in your example